# After some running time Telegram Bot stops and gives an error

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
user@instance-1:~$ sudo systemctl status telegrambot.service 
● telegrambot.service - Telegram Bot
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/telegrambot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-05-16 07:43:49 UTC; 42min ago
    Process: 40184 ExecStart=/home/user/telegrambot/venv/bin/python /home/user/telegrambot/bot.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 40184 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 python[40184]:     result = _get_req_session().request(method, request_url, params=params, files=files,
May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 python[40184]:   File "/home/user/telegrambot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 python[40184]:     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 python[40184]:   File "/home/user/telegrambot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 python[40184]:     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 python[40184]:   File "/home/user/telegrambot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 python[40184]:     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 python[40184]: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))
May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 systemd[1]: telegrambot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 16 07:43:49 instance-1 systemd[1]: telegrambot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Can someone help me with this issue? Server running on Ubuntu at Google Cloud Platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)  # or just print(e) if you don't have logger,
        # or import traceback; traceback.print_exc() for print full info
        time.sleep(15)
```